# Why isn't mediapipe drawing the landmarks on the live feed

Tags: machine-learning, error-handling, mediapipe

This is the code I got from the mediapipe documentation. I tried a lot of ways to which how I can showcase the landmark graph onto live feed but nothing seems to work. I could really use some help to understand what is going on here that I am missing out.

```
import mediapipe as mp
from mediapipe.tasks import python
from mediapipe.tasks.python import vision
import cv2
import time
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np
from mediapipe import solutions
from mediapipe.framework.formats import landmark_pb2
import numpy as np

MARGIN = 10  # pixels
FONT_SIZE = 1
FONT_THICKNESS = 1
HANDEDNESS_TEXT_COLOR = (88, 205, 54) # vibrant green

BaseOptions = mp.tasks.BaseOptions
HandLandmarker = mp.tasks.vision.HandLandmarker
HandLandmarkerOptions = mp.tasks.vision.HandLandmarkerOptions
HandLandmarkerResult = mp.tasks.vision.HandLandmarkerResult
VisionRunningMode = mp.tasks.vision.RunningMode

# Create a hand landmarker instance with the live stream mode:
def print_result(result: mp.tasks.vision.HandLandmarkerResult, output_image: mp.Image, timestamp_ms: int):
    print('hand landmarker result: {}'.format(result))

options = HandLandmarkerOptions(
    base_options=BaseOptions(model_asset_path='hand_landmarker.task'),
    running_mode=VisionRunningMode.LIVE_STREAM,
    result_callback=print_result)
with HandLandmarker.create_from_options(options) as landmarker:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        frame_np = np.array(frame)
        timestamp = int(round(time.time()*1000))
        mp_image = mp.Image(image_format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB, data=frame_np)
        frame = mp_image.numpy_view()
        result = landmarker.detect_async(mp_image, timestamp)
        if type(result) is not type(None):
           hand_landmarks_list = result.hand_landmarks
           for idx in range(len(hand_landmarks_list)):
                hand_landmarks = hand_landmarks_list[idx]

                # Draw the hand landmarks.
                hand_landmarks_proto = landmark_pb2.NormalizedLandmarkList()
                hand_landmarks_proto.landmark.extend([
                landmark_pb2.NormalizedLandmark(x=landmark.x, y=landmark.y, z=landmark.z) for landmark in hand_landmarks
                ])
                solutions.drawing_utils.draw_landmarks(
                    frame,
                    hand_landmarks_proto,
                    solutions.hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS,
                    solutions.drawing_styles.get_default_hand_landmarks_style(),
                    solutions.drawing_styles.get_default_hand_connections_style())                      
        else: 
            print('else')
        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I also keep getting this NoneType error everytime I pass the "results function". I have no clue how to handle that as well. THe mediapipe documentation does not give any insight on how to show this in a live feed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a patch to make your program work. You helped me, so I hope can help you back.

```
$ diff -c original.py new.py
*** original.py 2023-08-10 06:40:03.058934600 -0500
--- new.py      2023-08-10 06:40:17.938937500 -0500
***************
*** 27,32 ****
--- 27,33 ----
  options = HandLandmarkerOptions(
      base_options=BaseOptions(model_asset_path='hand_landmarker.task'),
      running_mode=VisionRunningMode.LIVE_STREAM,
+     num_hands=2,
      result_callback=print_result)
  with HandLandmarker.create_from_options(options) as landmarker:
      cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Comment: Note that your left hand is what google says it is, your right hand as appears to the webcam.  And vica versa.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.
In my case, where I used class, it worked when I stored the result from result_callback function (Mine is return_result) to a class variable.

```
def return_result(self, result: mp.tasks.vision.HandLandmarkerResult, output_image: mp.Image, timestamp_ms: int):
        self.detection_result = result

def detect(self, image, ts=None):
    if self.input_type == 'LIVE_STREAM':
        self.detector.detect_async(image, ts)

    return self.detection_result
```

and later called the detect function to get the result.

```
detectedResults = detector.detect(convertedFrame, frameNo)
```

**With your code, used a 'global' RESULT variable as below**

```
import mediapipe as mp
from mediapipe.tasks import python
from mediapipe.tasks.python import vision
import cv2
import time
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np
from mediapipe import solutions
from mediapipe.framework.formats import landmark_pb2
import numpy as np

MARGIN = 10  # pixels
FONT_SIZE = 1
FONT_THICKNESS = 1
HANDEDNESS_TEXT_COLOR = (88, 205, 54)  # vibrant green

BaseOptions = mp.tasks.BaseOptions
HandLandmarker = mp.tasks.vision.HandLandmarker
HandLandmarkerOptions = mp.tasks.vision.HandLandmarkerOptions
HandLandmarkerResult = mp.tasks.vision.HandLandmarkerResult
VisionRunningMode = mp.tasks.vision.RunningMode

RESULT = None


# Create a hand landmarker instance with the live stream mode:
def print_result(result: mp.tasks.vision.HandLandmarkerResult, output_image: mp.Image, timestamp_ms: int):
    # print(result)
    global RESULT
    RESULT = result


options = HandLandmarkerOptions(
    base_options=BaseOptions(model_asset_path='hand_landmarker.task'),
    running_mode=VisionRunningMode.LIVE_STREAM,
    result_callback=print_result)
with HandLandmarker.create_from_options(options) as landmarker:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        frame_np = np.array(frame)
        timestamp = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
        mp_image = mp.Image(image_format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB, data=frame_np)
        frame = mp_image.numpy_view()
        landmarker.detect_async(mp_image, timestamp)
        if type(RESULT) is not type(None):
            hand_landmarks_list = RESULT.hand_landmarks
            for idx in range(len(hand_landmarks_list)):
                hand_landmarks = hand_landmarks_list[idx]

                # Draw the hand landmarks.
                hand_landmarks_proto = landmark_pb2.NormalizedLandmarkList()
                hand_landmarks_proto.landmark.extend([
                    landmark_pb2.NormalizedLandmark(x=landmark.x, y=landmark.y, z=landmark.z) for landmark in
                    hand_landmarks
                ])
                solutions.drawing_utils.draw_landmarks(
                    frame,
                    hand_landmarks_proto,
                    solutions.hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS,
                    solutions.drawing_styles.get_default_hand_landmarks_style(),
                    solutions.drawing_styles.get_default_hand_connections_style())
        else:
            print('else')
        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```